# Zoomable image in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to make an image zoomable in my windows phone 7 application. (code below) however it dosent work, the image dosent display. Can someone put me on the right track, is this the right control to use? If it is then what am I doing wrong?

```
        <controls:PivotItem Name="Header" Header="item1">
            <Grid>
                <MultiScaleImage Name="mainImage" />
            </Grid>
        </controls:PivotItem>

        var imageurl = loginxml.Descendants("response").Elements("submissions").Elements("submission").Elements("file_url_screen").First().Value;
        //imageurl = https://inkbunny.net///files/screen/165/165693_CobaltHusky_random_anatomy_doodles.png
        Header.Header = loginxml.Descendants("response").Elements("submissions").Elements("submission").Elements("title").First().Value;
         DeepZoomImageTileSource img = new DeepZoomImageTileSource(new Uri(imageurl));
        mainImage.Source = img;
```

**EDIT** Reading the msdn on MultiScaleImage that isnt the control to use. It needs a specific image source (not a bitmap/jpg)

Comment: do you mean you want to Scale up the image based on User interaction ?

Comment: I want it to work exactly the same as the photo library in the phone. You can zoom in and out by pinching

Comment: Start with a ScrollViewer control instead of the grid and add an image into it. To Scale up and down use the Touch events ManipulationStarted,Delta and completed and based on the delta scale up or down the image. Hope this helps. I know the Magnifier app on the marketplace uses this.

Comment: About the Image not being able to display, what is the resource type of the image Content/Embedded Resource ? You will have to use the correct path to locate the image within your app.

Comment: @softwaredeveloper the image is downloaded from the web. Why is ScrollViewer better than MultiScaleImage? Do you know why MultiScaleImage isn't working? I would rather understand the problem than just change technologies.

Comment: I have not worked with MSI yet. Hopefully someone else should be able to chipin. About Image not being displayed after being downloaded from the web, does a local image display correctly ? are you saving into to the 'ISOStore' and reading it from there? Did it completely download ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The URL for the DeepZoomImageTileSource is not an image url, but the url to a XML file listing the images to use for the deep zoom tiles.

I implemented a simple zoomable image as follows using the silverlight toolkit:

```
<Image Name="MainImage" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" CacheMode="BitmapCache">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform x:Name="transform" />
    </Image.RenderTransform>
    <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <toolkit:GestureListener PinchStarted="OnPinchStarted" PinchDelta="OnPinchDelta" />
    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
</Image>
```

and in code:

```
MainImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(url));
```

Then declare two variables for your angle and zoom:

```
double initialAngle;
double initialScale;
```

And then handle the gesture events:

```
private void OnPinchStarted(object sender, PinchStartedGestureEventArgs e)
{
    initialAngle = transform.Rotation;
    initialScale = transform.ScaleX;
}

private void OnPinchDelta(object sender, PinchGestureEventArgs e)
{
    //transform.Rotation = initialAngle + e.TotalAngleDelta;
    transform.ScaleX = initialScale * e.DistanceRatio;
    transform.ScaleY = initialScale * e.DistanceRatio;
}
```

Uncomment the rotation line if you want to handle rotating the image as well.

Sam

Answer (score 0):

http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/MultiTouch